# How to search by tagnames with a comma between every search term with php

Tags: php, search, input, tags

I want to search **tags** by a comma between every search term. And if one or more of the terms exists in the table rows, the result will be posted. But I can not handle it with a comma between every term. Is there an easy way to do this? Please reply only if you have some suggestions to my question.

```
//HTML
<form method="POST" action="actionpage.php">
<input type="text" name="searchterm" value="**To be submitted with a comma between every tag  name**" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


//PHP
$tagname = [];
$tagname[] = $_POST['searchterm'].",";
$tagname[] = $_POST['searchterm'].",";
$tagname[] = $_POST['searchterm'].",";


// MySQL
query = "SELECT * FROM list where tags = $tagname";


// Database table list
id----------tagname
1           tag1,
1           tag2,
1           tag5,
2           tag2,
2           tag3,
3           tag1,
4           tag4,
4           tag1, etc...
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Can you have more than one tagname in a row in the database? If yes, are them comma separated? If there's only one, is there still a comma at the end of the tagname?

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't have any form elements called `searchterm1`, `searchterm2` and so on, but rather just one field called `searchterm`? And why do you have commas after the tags in the database? What is the `id` in your db?

Comment: I made some changes now. I hope I am more close to what I wanted to ask.

Comment: It's not. There are still some unanswered questions in the comments. Btw, is the code your _actual_ code or just pseudo code for our benefit?

Comment: @Magnus, It is just a pseudo to explain what I want to achieve. I want to get results from submitted tagnames.

Comment: There's too many issues with the little snippet you made. 1. You're creating an array which you're trying to echo inside a `WHERE`-statement. 2. You write `where tags = ` while you write that your database column is called `tagname`. 3. Why would you repeat the same tag multiple time in an array to start with?

Comment: You need to make some real attempts. Then if something fails, come back, show us the real attempt (copy/paste), what the expected output should be and what actually happens.

Comment: I repeat them because multiple rows can have same tag. The array is supposed to be the search items.

Comment: That's not how you do it. I would recommend reading some PHP/MySQL tutorials. This question is actually too broad for SO (which is for _specific_ issues with your _existing_ code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect what you are looking for is php 'explode' and 'implode'.

// get array of tags from searchterm
$tagname = explode(',', $_POST['searchterm']);

I didn't test the following, but it will give you an idea of what you need to do.  The query will fail is not tags provided.

$query = "SELECT * FROM list where tags in ('" . implode('\',\'', $tagname) . "')";

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. I hope it works. Thanks!

Comment: I just want to point out that this code is wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Specially since the user inputs aren't escaped at all! _Never ever_ trust user inputs of any kind.